# Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired 403

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to write my test spring security application with mkyong examples.

```
Spring Security: 4.0.0.RC1
Spring: 4.1.4.RELEASE
```

I have the following security config:

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" 
                    access="hasRole('ADMIN')"/>
    <form-login authentication-failure-url="/?auth_error" 
                        username-parameter="user" 
                        password-parameter="password" 
                        login-page="/"
                        default-target-url="/?OK"/>
<!-- <csrf/> -->
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="mkyong" password="123456" authorities="ADMIN" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

login-page:

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="POST">
    <label for="user">User: </label>
    <input type="text" id="user" name="user" /> </br>
    <label for="password">Password: </label>
    <input type="text" name="password" id="password" /> </br>
    <input type="submit" /> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, when I try to login I get 403 error page:

```
Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter 
'_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.
```

description:

```
Access to the specified resource (Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was
found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.) has been 
forbidden.
```

What's wrong, how can I fix that? I commented `csrf` in the config, but the error-message has to do with the `csrf`.

Answer (score 44):

I had the same problem. I use thymeleaf and Spring boot, and got the CSRF token issue when I try to post data in a form.

Here is my working solution:

1. Add this hidden input:

   `<input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}" />`
2. In your `WebSecurityConfig` (which extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`), add a method:

   ```
   private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() 
   { 
       HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository(); 
       repository.setSessionAttributeName("_csrf");
       return repository; 
   }
   ```

   and add code in method `configure()`:

   ```
   @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf()
        .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
   ```

I spent lot of time on this problem.  Hope it can help someone who has the same problem.

Comment: Your hidden input is actually hidden.

Comment: I think you don't need extra workaround. Just add hidden input with th:value and th:name.

Comment: I got the same issue after hot redeploys.  I was using JSPs with the Spring forms taglib, so no need for step 1, but step 2 alone solved the problem for me.

Comment: Does this for me :( Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.

Comment: This solution works for me but there is an issue - When I click on the browser back button and go out of the login page and click on forward button to come back to the application I get 'Status: 403 ERROR: Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired?' An idea how to  address this particular issues? TIA

Answer (score 25):

If you must disable it...

In Spring Security 4, [CSRF is enabled by default](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2347) when using the XML configuration. Previously it was only enabled by default for the Java-based configuration.

According to [Section 14.4.2 of the Spring Security Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-configure):

> As of Spring Security 4.0, CSRF protection is enabled by default with XML configuration. If you would like to disable CSRF protection, the corresponding XML configuration can be seen below.

```
<http>
   ...
   <csrf disabled="true"/>
   ...
</http>
```

Comment: Interesting, but how could I provide a valid csrf token if I'd like to use csrf? Is it possible?

Answer (score 19):

Disabling CSRF protection sounds like a bad idea, no?

If you use Spring's Form Tag library the CSRF token will be automatically included. It will also HTML Escape form element values, which makes your site safer against XSS, and more correct.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %> 

<form:form>
  <form:input...
</form:form>
```

Otherwise, add this to your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

To @St.Antario,
  Please use this code to enable CSRF in your code

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .antMatcher("*/*").authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
                .and().addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), SessionManagementFilter.class);
    }

    private Filter csrfHeaderFilter() {
        return new OncePerRequestFilter() {

            @Override
            protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                            HttpServletResponse response,
                                            FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

                CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
                if (csrf != null) {
                    Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
                    String token = csrf.getToken();
                    if (cookie == null || token != null
                            && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {

                        // Token is being added to the XSRF-TOKEN cookie.
                        cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
                        cookie.setPath("/");
                        response.addCookie(cookie);
                    }
                }
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        };
    }

    private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
        HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
        repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
        //repository.setSessionAttributeName(("X-XSRF-TOKEN"));
        return repository;
    }
}
```

Comment: can u please help me with a webflux version of ur code.

Answer (score 4):

### Problem:

In Spring Boot 2.7, the `csrf` is **DISABLED** by default.

In Spring Boot 3.x, the `csrf` is **ENABLED** by default.

### Solution

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@Configuration
public class ReactiveWebfluxSecurityConfig {

  @Bean
  public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http.csrf(ServerHttpSecurity.CsrfSpec::disable);
    return http.build();
  }
}
```

###### Note

**DON'T FORGET** to add `@Configuration` to the `@EnableWebFluxSecurity` as in Spring 3.0 it has to be explicitly added as I've done in the above code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

**spring-security.xml**

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />

    <http use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="isAnonymous()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <form-login
            login-page="/login"
            default-target-url="/home"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" /> 
        <logout
            logout-success-url="/login"
            delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
    </http>
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="carlos" password="123" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml, /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

**add add jsp login**

```
<%@page session="true"%>
```

**and input hidden:**

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

What is your login page named
Is it ending with .jsp

If the login page is not ending with .jsp Spring framework doesn't evaluate the JSP or EL expressions