# HTTP Status 403 - Expected CSRF token not found

Tags: java, angularjs, http, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am doing post to the server from the angular $http and I am getting

```
HTTP Status 403 - Expected CSRF token not found.
```

As I could find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28138864/expected-csrf-token-not-found-has-your-session-expired-403) one solution is to disable the CSRF, but I am not sure that is what I want. Please let me know how to solve this problem.

I am using Angular JS in the front end and Spring MVC 4 with Spring security 3.2 at the server side.

**Edit:**

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/signin")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/signin/authenticate")
                .failureUrl("/signin?param.error=bad_credentials")
            .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/signout")
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("search/**", "/c/**","/admin/**", "/favicon.ico", "/resources/**", "/auth/**", "/signin/**", "/signup/**", "/disconnect/facebook"/*, "/**"*/).permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
            .and()
                .rememberMe()
            .and()
                .apply(
                    new SpringSocialConfigurer());
    }
```

**Angular JS ajax request :**

```
$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'addCampaign',
        data: JSON.stringify(newCampaign)
    }).
    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

        //TODO Notification to show the campaign was successfully saved
        $log.info("campaign successfully saved");
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $log.info("campaign could not be saved" + data + " " + status + " " + headers + " " + config);
        //TODO to show notification that the campaign could not be saved succeffsully.
    });
```

Comment: You should show us your server side config for CRSF and your client side code.

Comment: @RC. I have edited my answer to include the code.

Comment: @codeMan did you found the solution?

Comment: @5er Yes, I found a solution to this problem. Please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem.

I figured out that spring will add the following two attributes in to the JSP view that I will return

```
`${_csrf.token}` and `${_csrf.headerName}`
```

and I am collecting those attributes in the `meta` tags in `JSP`

```
<meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}" />

<meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}" />
```

In the Javascript, I wrote the following function,

```
function getMetaContentByName(name, content) {
    var content = (content == null) ? 'content' : content;
    return document.querySelector("meta[name='" + name + "']").getAttribute(content);
}
```

While sending the ajax request, I am including the CRFS token that is present-

```
        $http({
            method: 'POST',

            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': getMetaContentByName('_csrf');
            },

            url: requestURL,
            data: data
        }).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

            $log.info("data : " + data);


        })
```