# Cannot disable csrf Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I'm developing an android app and I'm using Spring as a REST backend.

Every time I try to make post request to the server I get a 403 response with this message "Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired?".

I tried to disable csrf in the application.properties and with my own `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` implementation but to no avail.

Did I miss something ?

Comment: Add more details about your configurations, project structure and other related stuff.

Comment: would this help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28138864/expected-csrf-token-not-found-has-your-session-expired-403

Comment: I use auth0 as an authentication library which is an implementation of the jwt based security method. It has integration with the spring framework as a backend. The problem is I think that it has csrf enabled by default. And I cannot manually edit the configuration files provided by the library. And neither of the methods I sited in my post help.

Comment: I don't want to manage the csrf header since it's only required if my application is accessed by browser clients and I'm only accessing it from a non-browser client.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
.invalidateHttpSession(true)
.and()
.exceptionHandling()
.authenticationEntryPoint(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint())
.and()
.csrf()//Disabled CSRF protection
.disable();
```

Add this on your `logoutSuccessHandler(...)`

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to disable CSRF in Spring boot , by default in spring boot is enable

**1. By Java Configuration**

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
   http.csrf().disable();
}
```

**2. By Application.yml**

```
 security.enable-csrf: false
```

Comment: security.enable-csrf has been deprecated