# CSRF token invalidated when browser back button is clicked

Tags: csrf, csrf-token

I have enabled the CSRF protection on the login page as advised in the link below and got it working,

[Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired 403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28138864/expected-csrf-token-not-found-has-your-session-expired-403)

Unfortunately it is failing in the following scenario,

From the login screen, when the user Navigate back using browser back button and Navigate forward using browser forward button to land on the login page, I get 'Status: 403 ERROR: Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired?'

An idea how to address this particular issues? Thanks